# ASP.net C# AsyncPostBacktriggerr Click event Doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have the below code written in  *ASP.net C#*.

**NOTE** My modal view everythings works perfectly **but** the button's doesn't fire click event.

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>        
    <div>
        <div>
            <div class="wrapperDiv">
                <div class="headerDiv">
                    <h3 class="title"></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="contentDiv">   
                     <div class="gridWrapper">
                        <div >
                            <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Yeni Sevkiyat" class="btn btn-primary"/>&nbsp;

                            <asp:Button ID="btnsil" runat="server" Text="Sil" class="btn btn-primary" 
                            OnClientClick="return confirm('Sevkiyatı Silmek İstediğinizden Eminmisiniz?');" />&nbsp;

                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Müşteri Adına Göre : "></asp:Label>

                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server"  class="form-control" 
                            style="margin-top: 5px;"></asp:TextBox>

                            <asp:Button ID="btnara" runat="server" Text="Ara!" class="btn btn-primary"/>

                        </div>
                        <!-- Start of Gridview-->
                         <div class="gridContainer">
                             <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                     <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EmptyDataText="Kayıt Bulunamadı"
                                         class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanged="GridView1_PageIndexChanged" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
                                         <Columns>
                                             <asp:BoundField DataField="sprno" HeaderText="Sipariş No" SortExpression="sprsno" />
                                             <asp:BoundField DataField="sprssorumlu" HeaderText="Sipariş Sorumlusu" SortExpression="sprssorumlu" />
                                              <asp:BoundField DataField="musteri" HeaderText="Müşteri Adı" SortExpression="musteri" />
                                             <asp:BoundField DataField="sevkili" HeaderText="Sevk İli" SortExpression="sevkili" />
                                             <asp:BoundField DataField="sevkadresi" HeaderText="Sevk Adresi" SortExpression="sevkadresi" />
                                             <asp:BoundField DataField="sevksaati" HeaderText="Sevk Saati" SortExpression="sevksaati" />
                                             <asp:BoundField DataField="sevkdurumu" HeaderText="Sevk Durumu" SortExpression="sevkdurumu" />

                                             <asp:BoundField DataField="sprstarihi" HeaderText="Sipariş Tarihi" SortExpression="sprstarihi"
                                                 DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
                                             <asp:BoundField DataField="sevktarihi" HeaderText="Sevk Tarihi" SortExpression="sevktarihi"
                                                 DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
                                              <asp:BoundField DataField="sevkurun" HeaderText="Sevk Edilecek Ürünler" SortExpression="sevkurun" />
                                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Düzenle | Sil">

                                                 <ItemTemplate>
                                                     <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CommandName="select" 
                                                     CommandArgument='<%# Eval("sprno") %>'>Düzenle</asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;
                                                     <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDelete" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" />
                                                     <asp:HiddenField ID="hfEmpId" runat="server" value='<%# Eval("sprno") %>'/>
                                                 </ItemTemplate>
                                             </asp:TemplateField>
                                         </Columns>
                                     </asp:GridView>          
                                </ContentTemplate
```

**In here triggers doesn't work. This created modal's button's.**

```
                                <Triggers>                                             
                                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnkaydet" EventName="Click" />     
                                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnsil" EventName="Click" />
                                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnara" EventName="Click" />
                                </Triggers>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>  
                         </div>
                         <!-- End of Gridview-->
                     </div>          
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Which is the button that doesn't fire click event?

Comment: btnkaydet, btnsil and btnara button's doesn't click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `OnClick` the attribute in the buttons

```
<asp:Button ID="btnara" runat="server" Text="Ara!" class="btn btn-primary" OnClick="btnara_Click" />
```

Comment: ok. but btnkaydet is in the modal view also it doesn't fire too

Comment: ara button is now working. But in the modal view btnkaydet still doesn't work.

Comment: I can't see that button in your code, but did you already add the attributes `OnClick="btnkaydet_Click"` and `AutoPostBack="true"`

Comment: in the trigger section there are 3 AsyncPostBackTrigger and all of them button in the modal view

Comment: OK i added button and everythings working fine =) Thank you so much